# Infinite product $\prod_p (1+p^{-2}+p^{-3} +\dots+p^{-k})$

Tags: prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

The question is for what integers $k$ s does the product $$ \prod_p (1+p^{-2}+p^{-3} +\dots+p^{-k})$$ have a nice closed form where the product is being taken over all prime. (the $p^{-1}$ term is suppose to be missing by the way, its not a typo)

**Motivation**

So in a math discord server we were discussing a problem, namely to find the sum:
$$J(k) = \lim_{N\to \infty} \dfrac{1}{N} \sum_{N\geq n\geq 1} \dfrac{\sigma(n^k)}{n^k}$$ inspired By the famous case that $J(1)=\zeta(2)$ ofcourse. Now after some computations we found $J(2) = \dfrac{\zeta(2)\zeta(3)}{\zeta(4)}$ and then that 
$$J(k)=\lim_{N\to \infty} \dfrac{1}{N} \sum_{N\geq n\geq 1} \dfrac{\sigma(n^k)}{n^k}=\zeta(k+1) \prod_p (1+p^{-2}+p^{-3} +\dots+p^{-k})$$
The infinite limit is also nice, it is $\dfrac{\zeta(2)\zeta(3)}{\zeta(6)}$. I was wondering if there was some other values of $k$ for which this $J(k)$ had a nice closed form.

Comment: When you write the infinite limit is $\dfrac{\zeta(2)\zeta(3)}{\zeta(6)}$, is that as $k \to \infty$?

Comment: @VVejalla: Yes. This is [Landau's totient constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totient_summatory_function#The_summatory_of_reciprocal_totient_function).

Comment: $+1$ – those are some beautiful results! Unfortunately I doubt that any of the others will have a nice closed form. [Sarnak's constant](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SarnaksConstant.html) (without closed form) has a form similar to that of $J(3)$, but $p+2$ instead of $p+1$ in the numerator. You may want to take a look at [Euler product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_product) at Wikipedia and [Prime products](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeProducts.html) at MathWorld if you haven't already done so, but I don't think any of that helps here.

Comment: Thanks, and yeah that is my expectation; that pretty much nothing else has a nice closed form. I do hope someone has seen something like this and can give a nice closed form. Also yeah those pages is how i discovered the nice value for the infinite limit.